# voting bar showing no of votes

Tags: jquery

I want a jquery plugin which shows dynamic bar consisting of no of votes from database,when a user points to that voting tab.please suggest .

Comment: Any solution will have to encompass more than jQuery. jQuery is client side, and you will need some server side part to store the number of votes. Adding full details of your set-up may help get answers.

But then, with the success of http://disqus.com/ you would think some 3rd party would offer a service you can just drop on to your website to do this. They probably already do and I just haven't heard of them.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [jqBarGraph](http://workshop.rs/jqbargraph/).